# Move SVN repository to Bitbucket

Tags: git, svn, version-control, bitbucket

A step by step on how to move SVN repository to Bitbucket on linux.

I have some repositories in SVN that I would like to move to Bitbucket, if anyone know's how to do it via linux commands, I'd really appreciate it, so I can turn it into a script.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Bitbucket hosts git and Mercurial repositories, so you must decide if you gonna use git or hg. And why there is "github" tag?

Comment: So do you want to migrate a svn repo to git repo and then psh the git repo to bitbucket?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT yes please, I’d greatly appreciate your help

Comment: @MikeShobes I add the way to migrate svn repo to git, you can have a try.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Thanks so much!! Can I use a “svn checkout” instead?

Comment: @MikeShobes Nope, `svn checkout` command can not mtgrate svn repo to git.

Comment: @MikeShobes Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer (√ symbol on the left on the answer). And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `git svn clone` command to migrate svn repo to git repo. Detail steps as below:

```
git svn clone <URL for svn repo>
# besides you can use --trunk, --branches and --tags etc for git svn clone command
# may be asked to enter SVN credentials

# after first creating the repo in bitbucket...
cd reponame
git remote add origin <bitbucket repo URL>
# you may also need to "git pull --allow-unrelated-histories" to merge you new local branch with the remote
# you may need to do a "git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master"
# you may also need to another "git pull --allow-unrelated-histories" to merge you new local branch with the remote
git push origin --all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git svn clone --username <user_name> <SVN_Repo_url> --trunk=trunk --branches=branches --tags=tags
cd <Repo>/
#Provide branch names that are inside the Branchs dir
remote_branches=("branch1" "branch2" "branch3" "branch4")
 
for branch in "${remote_branches[@]}"; do
    git remote add origin  <Bitbucket_repo_url>
    git checkout -b "$branch" "remotes/origin/$branch"
    git push -u origin "$branch"
done
#Provide your own tags inside the Tags dir
tags=("develop.0.0.1" "develop.0.1.2" "feature.0.0.1" "feature.0.1.2" "QA.0.0.1" "QA.0.1.2")
 
for tag in "${tags[@]}"; do
    git remote add origin  <Bitbucket_repo_url>
    git tag "$tag" "remotes/origin/tags/$tag"
    git push -u origin "$tag"
done
 
trunks=("trunk")
 
for tag in "${trunks[@]}"; do
    git remote add origin  <Bitbucket_repo_url>
    git tag "$trunks" "remotes/origin/$trunks"
    git push -u origin "$trunks"
done
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).